# Splitting list into multiple lists to gain a speedup?

Tags: python, performance, list, nested-lists

Let's say my list is about `1,000,000` entries long. To acess an item, the time would be `O(500,000)`, which seems very long to me.

What happens when I split the list up into multiple lists ? Let's look at an example:
Splitting the list into 10 parts, I'd have a list as follows:

```
splitted_list = [
    [list with 100,000 entries],
    [list with 100,000 entries],
    [list with 100,000 entries],
    [list with 100,000 entries],
    [list with 100,000 entries],
    [list with 100,000 entries],
    [list with 100,000 entries],
    [list with 100,000 entries],
    [list with 100,000 entries],
    [list with 100,000 entries]
]
```

The time to acess an item would be `O(5) + O(50,000) = O(50,005)` and gives a speedup about 1000% !

When splitting the original list about it's root, which is `1000` in this case, this would give us a list containg 1000 lists having another 1000 entries.

```
splitted_list = [
    [list with 1000 entries],
    [list with 1000 entries],
    [list with 1000 entries],
    [list with 1000 entries],
    ...
]
```

Now take a look at the time to acess an item:

```
O(500) + O(500) = O(1000)
O(1000) < O(50,005) < O(500,000)
```

This is the optimal speed up about 1000 times ! Incredible to belive, I think, so my question:

### Does this apply in practice, too, or is this just theory ?

Comment: Please don't write things like "O(500)". That means _exactly the same_ as O(1), namely "uses the same amount of resources no matter how large the input is". The big-O notation _requires_ that what's inside the parentheses is a function of an _unknown_ variable; otherwise it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is that you are thinking of [linked lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list), in which each element holds a pointer to the next. These have O(n) indexing, since the only way to get the nth element is to walk through the list from the beginning.

Your idea is related to various data structures, of which the closest is probably a [skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list). This is a data structure based on a linked list but with "highways" of nodes that skip ahead more than one element of the list. The advantage is that you can run down the highway to get to the middle of the list, and then drop down to the "slower lanes" when you need individual-element precision, giving O(log n) indexing efficiency -- the same as a [binary tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree). Of course, the downside is that it's more complicated (and slower) to perform other linked-list operations such as random inserts.

Python lists, however, are implemented under-the-hood as dynamically growing [arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure). These have O(1) indexing, since to get the third element you can simply add three (units) to the memory address of the first element, without having to traverse all elements in between.

You may be interested in the [Wikipedia article on data structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures).

Answer (score 5):

Get item by index from list [is O(1)](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) whatever the size of the list.

Comment: Oh lol, why did I think this is `O(1/2 * length)` ? I guess someone told me.. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I remember, a professor in the University told me in a workshop. O.o

Comment: Access an element by index is O(1). Finding out the index of an element takes on average 1/2 * length steps. Maybe that is what you are talking about?

Comment: @Niklas, I get the feeling your professor was talking about a different implementation of a list. Perhaps a doubly-linked list, like the `collections.deque` that is mentioned in the URL in this solution.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that you are talking about finding an element in the lists.

If you are talking about splitting a sorted list into many sorted lists with pointers to their heads, congratulations, you have almost discovered the B-tree.

If those lists are really arrays (i.e. you have constant-time random access), you can also do a binary search.